# What’s the full sentence for ‘no’?

Tags: meaning, negation

> “If all the world hated you, and believed you wicked, while your own
>   conscience approved you, and absolved you from guilt, you would not be
>   without friends.”
>  “**No**; I know I should think well of myself; but
>   that is not enough: if others don’t love me I would rather die than
>   live—I cannot bear to be solitary and hated, Helen.  Look here; to
>   gain some real affection from you, or Miss Temple, or any other whom I
>   truly love, I would willingly submit to have the bone of my arm
>   broken, or to let a bull toss me, or to stand behind a kicking horse,
>   and let it dash its hoof at my chest—” (Jane Eyre)

Comment: I think this question was improperly closed, because the closevoters did not realize that bare *No* is often classified as a one-word sentence or as a pro-form standing for a complete sentence. I urge it be reopened, so that closure will not cause visitors to overlook it.

Comment: @StoneyB I think the problem here was that the question isn't clear from either the title or the description.

Comment: The actual question is unfortunately only in the title, but it seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*No* denies a proposition which precedes it. How *far* back the negation extends must be inferred from the context, which happily is clear here: the speaker denies the proposition *you would not be without friends*. Her response may be paraphrased:

> No; *that is not so, for* I know *that under the circumstances described in your conditional clause*, I should think well of myself; but that is not enough *to justify the conclusion you draw: I **would** be ‘without friends’, for that requires that others love me. And* if others don't love me, &c